# How to apply SVG filters on HTML content in Opera?

Tags: javascript, svg, opera

How to apply SVG filters on xHTML content in Opera? (with javascript or with CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not yet possible. What you can do right now is use inline SVG and apply the filters to that instead.

Comment: What will be, if I will change <html> namespace to SVG?

Comment: That won't work. You will need to recreate the thing you want to apply the filter to in pure svg.